# Can the flashlight be recharged before it starts flickering?

Tags: the-last-of-us

When the flashlight in The Last Of Us starts flickering it needs to be recharged by shaking the controller. Can I prevent my flashlight from going out if I preemptively shake my controller before the flashlight starts flickering?